# How to query images out from mysql using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, image

I have a website and on the website I have images on all of the pages. I am adding functionality to be able to change any image on the website. SO I have images table  and images_allocation tables in my database.

My question is "What is best way to query out images from database and display them on web page." Do I have to query out all the images separately, so `Select * form images where imageid = 2` so for every image on database I have to have an separate query.

But having so many `SELECT` and `UPDATE` query will slow my website down.

Is there any better way to show images, and when user click the image, modal appear (which shows all images from database) and user can select the image to change.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <img alt="Start timer" id="idimg1" class="classimg" src="css/icons/timer-stop.png" >
   <div class="overlay">

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning img-upload" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" imgid= "idimg1" imgclass="classimg" >
   Edit
 </button>

   </div>
   </div>
```

**Modal**:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header"> 
         <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">Images/h3>
        <div class="text-center">
                <h4>Select Image</h4>
                 <form id="timer-reason">
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <?php
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($images)) {
                                ?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $row['imagedir_img']; echo $row['image_img']; ?>" style="width:20%;" class="img-gallary">

                                <?php 
                                 }
                                ?>

                             </div>
                            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="group button">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="submit-timer-reason" role="button" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </form>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".img-upload").click(function(){
         imdid = $(this).attr("imgid");
    });

    $(".img-gallary").click(function(){
        var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
        $("#"+ imdid).attr("src",imgsrc)

    }); 

});


</script>
```

Comment: I think your question might be a little too broad, you should post a reproducible code example if you want to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand all that you're asking, but I can answer this at least

> Do I have to query out all the images separately, so Select * form images where imageid = 2

No. If you want to select all of the images in the table, just leave out the WHERE clause of your query:

```
SELECT * FROM images
```

You can use that result to create your modal.